# How to place my panels and style up my page in GWT

Tags: gwt, styling, uibinder

I am working on a GWT website. I have completed the basic implementation part, and now I am at a stage where I have to style up my page. I have facing some hurdles in this part -

a) I am not sure how can I place various panels on my screen. Let us say I have two vertical panels and I want them to be paced such that they cover 100% space (first one covering say 70% and the second one covering remaining 30%). How do I do this?

b) I am using UiBinder. Should all this go in the UibInder xml? Or this should be a part of my CSS.

c) There are different hacks around doing such stuff all over the internet. What I am interested in knowing is the best and cleanest way to do this.

I know my question is vague, but I am looking for some links, tutorials, or even some sample code which can guide me through this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, I am a newbie, so forgive me for asking a very elementary question.

Comment: For a, you create a Grid with 1 row and 2 columns and you set width of 30% on the columnFormater for column 1 and 70% for column2. The grid itself you set it to height and width 100%. I don't use UIBinder but this is how to do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Best aproach is to look a the [MVP](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) Tutorial from google.

There will all your questions be answerd and you have a good basic knowledge.